# Replace pandas containing empty list with None

Tags: pandas

How can I replace `all` empty list `[]` values to `None` in the following df:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = pd.Timestamp.now()

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
              'col2': [1, list(), 3],
              'col3': ['x', 'y', list()],
              'col4': [d, d, d]})
```

The solution:
`df[df.applymap(lambda x: x == [])] = None` gives `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky! Because of the way pandas (and numpy) coerce lists, vectorizing this may actually be impossible. However, I might be wrong.

A clean, simple solution would be to use `applymap` to check if each value is `[]`, and then replace using that mask:

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x: x == [])] = None
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  col1  col2  col3
0    a     1     x
1    b  None     y
2    c     3  None
```

Comment: Yeah, the answer does not work for mixed-type df with datetime!

Answer (score 0):

Try `where`

```
df.where(df.astype(bool),None,inplace=True)
df
Out[419]: 
  col1  col2  col3
0    a     1     x
1    b  None     y
2    c     3  None
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using `applymap` with boolean mask with:

```py
import numpy as np
from collections.abc import Iterable

df[df.applymap(lambda x: len(x) == 0 if isinstance(x, Iterable) else False)] = np.nan
```